# Multiline textfield in iphone

Tags: iphone, textfield, multiline

I need to enter multiline text in the iphone text area. but the default textfiled is of single line. is there any way to make it multilined.

Thanks in advance,
Shibin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use UITextView instead